# Get Oracle trigger result from C program

Tags: c, oracle, triggers, daemon

I have a daemon written in C under linux and i want the daemon to be notified when a table inside an Oracle database has changed (update or insert in the table). It seems that a `Trigger` or `dbms_scheduler` may help, any ideas (snippets of code with an infinite while loop for example)? Thanks.

Comment: A better approach would be to use the DBMS_AQ package.  You can have the trigger post to a queue, and the c client wait for a queue entry to read back.  google DBMS_AQ and read the oracle docs about it.  It is more efficient than constantly polling a table.  Here is an example using OCI - http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B10500_01/appdev.920/a96587/qsample.htm  It is a lot of coding to do in C.  What do you need to do with the notification data?  If it is more database processing, then you can most likely do it all in the database with pl/sql.

Comment: Also, you don't mention what db access library you are using in your C program to access the database.  Please specify.

Comment: @OldProgrammer : i'm using Oracle PRO*C

Comment: OK, then that makes it a lot easier.  Take a look at DBMS_AQ.

Comment: @OldProgrammer : Thanks but it seems that ther's no API for PRO*C just for OCI!

Comment: You can call pl/sql in pro*c.  Good luck.